# Resque priority queue with Heroku & Procfile. Crashes

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, resque

On my local machine I can do

```
QUEUES=a,b,c,d rake resque:work
```

And it processes those queues in that order. However, on Heroku Cedar I add this to my procfile:

```
worker: QUEUES=a,b,c,d exec bundle exec rake resque:work
```

And it crashes the app on deploy. I'm probably missing something dumb, but I'm stumped.

PS I prefix the command with exec because of a bug with resque not properly decrementing the worker count.

Comment: are you using this branch `gem 'resque', :git => 'http://github.com/hone/resque.git', :branch => 'keepalive'` of resque when you deploy?

Comment: do you get any errors at all, either in console, or is the logs?

Comment: Getting an error: Error: No such file or directory -

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't need the initial `exec`. The entry should look like this:

```
worker: bundle exec rake resque:work QUEUE=a,b,c,d
```

Use @hone's fork to properly clean up workers when they quit. In your Gemfile:

```
gem 'resque', git: 'https://github.com/hone/resque.git', branch: 'heroku', require: 'resque/server'
```

Comment: I removed the exec and ended up using the keepalive branch that John mentioned. That fixed it up for me.